# How to fix postgresql update with join performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, spatial, spatial-query

I hawe geospatial tables named **`node`** and **`ways`**.

I want to set `end_node_id` column of `ways` table with `node` table attribute using spatial join. two tables have about 100K data.

```
update ways
set
    end_node_id = n.node_id
from
    ways w
inner join
    nodes n
on
    st_endpoint(w.shape) = n.shape;
```

But this query takes so many times. After 15 minutes I stopped the query. Is there any performence query for this operation?

Update Explain:

```
Update on ways w (cost=0.00..669909619.43 rows=24567397 width=576)  
->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..669909619.43 rows=24567397 width=576)
          Join Filter: (st_endpoint(w.shape) = n.shape)
          ->  Seq Scan on ways w (cost=0.00..8960.61 rows=120161 width=564)
          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..12200.81 rows=204454 width=52)
                        ->  Seq Scan on nodes n  (cost=0.00..9181.54 rows=204454 width=52)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include `ways` in the `from` clause!  This doesn't do what you expect.  Presumably, you want:

```
update ways w
    set end_node_id = n.node_id
from nodes n
where st_endpoint(w.shape) = n.shape;
```

In your formulation, the `ways` in the `update` is a *different* reference from the `ways` in the `from`.  So, your code is creating Cartesian product -- which no doubt slows down the processing.  Note that this is different from the behavior of SQL Server, which has similar syntax.

Comment: I tried this solution but it is executing for 1 hours, not complated yet.

Comment: @barteloma . . . I suspect that `nodes` is pretty big.  This is still doing a Cartesian product between `ways` and `nodes`.  You may need some specific geo indexes if you need to speed this up.

Comment: I have updated the post with explain. But I do not understand so much of explain. Both of tables have 100K data and they have spatial indexes.

Comment: @barteloma . . . Every row in `ways` has to be compared to 100,000 rows in `nodes`.  That takes a while, alas.

Comment: Yer right, but if I set the date filter `where created_at::date=current_date` the query takes long time yet.

Comment: Use `created_at >= current_date and created_at < current_date + interval '1 day'`.  This allows the query to use an index on `created_date`, assuming you have one.